# HP NC107i (BCM5723) on freebsd 9

Tags: freebsd, timeout, watchdog

We've purchased 3 hp proliant dl120 servers. They come with 2 integrated network adapters - HP NC107i PCIe Gigabit Server Adapter which is based on BCM5723.

After Freebsd 9 installation I've discovered a few problems.

1. After setting up bge0 network interfaces, I've noticed that I was temporarily losing connection with a server for short periods of time. /var/log/messages was filled up with "bge0: watchdog timeout -- resetting" messages.
2. I've switched to bge1 interface and after a few hours I've noticed that my server froze completely. I tried to do the same on the other server and got the same result.

I'm trying to understand what's going on and can provide more info on request.
If anyone could give me a clue if there is a way to fix this problem by patching bge driver or making some tweaks in BIOS ?

Alternatively I could install some linux version on that server instead of freebsd 9 or add discreet intel network adapter.

Comment: It might be worth asking on freebsd-net@freebsd.org so that the developers can help you directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added

```
hw.bge.allow_asf="0"
```

to my

```
/boot/loader.conf
```

in order to disable asf feature on broadcom ethernet controller.
Seems like it did the trick. 3 days and no messages or freezes so far.